# How to create a Spinner in PHP?

Tags: php, spinner

I have problem and I hope you help me, please.

I have a code:

```
$a = 'A B C D E';
$b = '{A|a|AA}{B|b|BB} {E|e|EEE}';
```

And I want to use **$b** to random display **$a** like this:

```
A b C D EE

AA B C D e

A b C D EEE ...
```

This mean:

> **A** replace to **A**,  **a** or **AA**
>
> **B** replace to **B**, **b** or **BB**
>
> and
>
> **E** replace to **E**, **e** or **EEE**

I hope you understand and help me, thankyou so much!!! <3

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And we will not write the code you need. So please show what you have tried.

Comment: First you must help yourself and show us some code you have tried.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO.  Your first output example: `A b C D EE` lists two Es whereas your recipe dictates `E replace to E, e or EEE`.  Is this a mistake?  Please edit your question to rectify.  Also add your previous workings/attempts and outcomes, if not your question will be likely downvoted and / or removed.

Comment: OMG. I have tried many times with every tutorials in Internet. But fail :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wedded to the format of $b, you could use arrays for substitutes, and pick a random item to replace.

```
$placeholders = 'A B C D E';
$substitutes  = [
        'A' => ['A','a','AA'],
        'B' => ['B','b','BB'],
        'E' => ['E','e','EE','EEE'],
];
$replacements = [];
foreach($substitutes as $key => $choices) {
    $random_key = array_rand($choices);
    $replacements[$key] = $choices[$random_key];
}
$spun = str_replace(
    array_keys($replacements),
    array_values($replacements),
    $placeholders
);
echo $spun;
```

Example output:

```
AA b C D EE
```

Alternatively (if your substitutes are uniform):

```
function substitute($character) {
    $random = rand(0,2);
    $string = $random
        ? str_repeat($character, $random) 
        : strtolower($character);
    return $string;
}

$spun = implode(
    ' ',
    array_map(
        'substitute', 
        ['A','B','C','D','E']
    )
);
echo $spun;
```

But the above will substitute for C and D also.  You could easily adapt for exclusions.